# Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView exception thrown

Tags: xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm trying to create a slider with CarouselView class, but I'm getting this exception and I don't know why:

**System.MissingMethodException = Method not found: void Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView.set_IndicatorView(Xamarin.Forms.IndicatorView)**.

I've already set `Forms.SetFlags("IndicatorView_Experimental")` in `MainActivity.cs`

Here's the code:

```
<StackLayout>
            <CarouselView x:Name="guidaView" IndicatorView="indicatorView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Subtitle}" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
            <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" 
                       IndicatorsShape="Square"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,40" />
        </StackLayout>
```

I'm using Xamarin.Forms (4.6.0.847 version) and Xamarin.Essentials (1.5.3.2)

Comment: I could not reproduce the error for `IndicatorView`. Could you provide the code sample which could reproduce for us? I tested on same version of Xamarin.Forms (4.6.0.847 version) and Xamarin.Essentials (1.5.3.2) with no error. You could check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/5cWQPQm And i upload the whole project on GitHub, you could downlaod for reference. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/IndicatorView

Comment: Solved: the version of the xamarin.forms package was not updated in Project.Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: the version of the xamarin.forms package was not updated in Project.Android